# Inappropriate Video Uploaded on Youtube

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I am working on this project where user can upload his/her video on my YouTube channel. I am using YouTube browser upload v2 API.Everything is working good and videos are uploading easily to my YouTube channel using a easy i have provided to the user.

Now my question is :

Since a lot of people going to upload videos on this channel through the interface.What if someone upload any inappropriate content[like any copyright video or pornography ] ??
I know YouTube review every video for inappropriate content and these kind of videos eventually gets deleted.

But my real concern is about other videos on the same channel which do not contain any inappropriate content, do they also gets deleted OR what about my account will it get blocked !!!

If my account can be blocked:
IS there any other way around of doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube will probably terminate your account if you (and by you i mean users of your app) keeps uploading videos that are in violation of their terms

read the Youtube terms

http://www.youtube.com/static?gl=CA&template=terms

See section 7

> YouTube will terminate a user's access to the Service if, under
>   appropriate circumstances, the user is determined to be a repeat
>   infringer.

Answer (score 1):

Ran in to this problem a while ago, actually there is a post on the youtube developer forums:

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/02/video-uploads-from-your-sites-community.html

Maby this will help you aswell